# Intel 660P SSD starts copying fast, then dramatically drops in speed a short way through

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have an Intel 660p Series M.2 2280 512GB PCIe NVMe 3.0 x4 3D2, QLC Internal Solid State Drive

Model is SSDPEKNW512G8X1

It was purchased in October of 2019 and is currently a little over 50% full.

I am running Windows 10 Pro, build 18363.9

Starting today, it seems to be having problems maintaining write speed.

If I copy a single 15GB file from one folder to another on the same drive, it starts out with a write speed of about 810MB/S, and then immediately starts ramping down to about 55MB/S, which it reaches after a few seconds, and then stays there for the rest of the copy.

TRIM is enabled.

The PC is not running hot and has more than adequate fans and air flow.

I am not sure what is wrong or why this suddenly started happening.

Comment: idk how to do this on Win, only on Mac, but investigate *manual* TRIM, which you can use periodically [like once a year, not every week] to TRIM all spare blocks. That way the drive isn't having to go through the whole 'erase to write' process every time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of this particular device. The write speed can reach as high as 500MB/s, provided there's plenty of empty cells available. But eventually you'll run out of them. Once that happens, you're limited to its rewrite speed, which varies from 50MB/s to 100MB/s. A firmware update might help.

Here's what [storagereview.com had to say](https://www.storagereview.com/review/intel-ssd-660p-series-review) (emphasis added):

"Looking at performance of the drive showed no surprises, as it was well behind the more expensive drives we compared it to. In the Houdini test the drive posted 4,070.6 seconds placing it near the bottom. In SQL Server the drive had 2,613.3 TPS and an average latency of 998ms, placing well behind the rest pack, while our VDI workload analyses showed more or less the same budget-friendly results. It was able to hit 4K peaks of 26,456 IOPS write and 60,604 IOPS read, **with 64K scores of 225MB/s read and 77.21MB/s write**. In our VDI tests the drive hit 24,164 IOPS boot, 8404 IOPS initial login, and 10,403 IOPS Monday login."

Comment: So you're saying that once all empty cells are used, this drive becomes *slower* than a regular platter drive for the rest of its life? Is this a problem with all SSDs or this model? If it's all SSDs, why does my 6 year-old Macbook Pro SSD still work perfectly fine?

Comment: This is correct.  Also, cache plays a large role in write speed.  Drives always operate fast at the start of a large write, as the cache is being written and read from.  Once the cache is filled and the long operation continues, the read and write speed slows down.

Comment: @AgmLauncher No, it's not slower than a regular patter drive for the rest of its life. First, it's only the sequential write speed that's slower. Random writes and reads of all kinds will be much faster. Second, it will recover some of its write speed if it has a rest from writing as it will restore its pool of erased blocks. This is a low-end SSD and this is its main weakness. It's suitable only for write-mostly workloads.